# Why does my hair material show up in little pixels on the rendered image?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, export

[image: Trunks in Unity][image: Trunks model]

When I look at my model in rendered mode, it shows up with these little pixels of hair material all over the model, and upon exporting to unity, shows up there too.

Here is the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V9xJWQUl2zWWVWzb-LnTZ-B_7juFKxD1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It would be helpful if you could upload that .blend file so we can take a look at it. 

Do those particles change color, when you tweak the hair material? Or could the be firefly artifacts?

Comment: I actually had to just remap all the bones and the problem fixed itself. However, after exporting it to Unity, many of the materials on the mesh have gone invisible. I'll try to see if i can upload the .blend file and a picture of what i'm seeing.

Comment: Do not forget to pack your textures. On my system, the clothes material is simply black. I also noticed that you have applied an emissive material on a lot of the parts. Was that on purpose?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the emissions out. How do I pack the textures? When I do it, I have about 40 errors coming onto my screen saying that i'm missing textures, but I deleted them because they were unnecessary.

Comment: In the Properties Window, select the material, that has a  texture on it, in your case the cloth material. Switch over to the Texture Tab and look for the Image drawer. On the left side of the file selector there is a little in-tray icon. That is for packing the texture.

Comment: Thanks for the all help, however, all of my textures were packed and i'm still missing the meshes in Unity.

Comment: Never-mind, I googled it and found a video explaining it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The missing meshes are likely from your flipped normals. Select all your faces and hit Ctrl + N to recalculate Outside Normals.